# How to select most suitable rule from generated association rules?

Tags: weka, data-mining, rapidminer

I generated association rules from "**Create Association Rules**" Operator. How do I select most interesting rule from these?

Created rules - https://ibb.co/duUoKF

Comment: I think you need to trust your  expert knowledge and/or the  "business logic" for prioritizing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your problem. Take the ones that make sense in regards to the question and then you could sort by support, lift or confidence.

Answer (score 1):

There are some 30 measures proposed for the "interestingness" of rules.

Implement one that you like.